# how to open fiddler saz files on mac or online?

Tags: web-hosting, web-development, mac

a friend sent me a fiddler record for me to watch.

I have mac and the file he has sent is `X.saz`

I could install fiddler on mac. How can i open these files to watch?

online opening is good as well

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to the [Fiddler Wiki](http://fiddler.wikidot.com/saz-files):

> SAZ files are simply specially formatted .ZIP files. If you rename a
>   .SAZ file to .ZIP, you can open it for viewing using standard ZIP
>   viewing tools.
>
> Inside a SAZ file, you will find:
>
> _index.htm - an optional file containing a human readable version of the Session List. This file is not processed when loading a .SAZ file
>   and exists solely for manual examination. [Content_Types.xml] — (Added
>   in v2.4.0.9) A metadata file which specifies a few MIME types so the
>   archive can be read by System.IO.Packaging or other clients that
>   support the Open Packaging Conventions. a raw folder - containing
>   files representing each web session. Inside the Raw folder, there will
>   be three files for each web session.
>
> sessid#_c.txt - contains the raw client request. sessid#_s.txt -
>   contains the raw server request. sessid#_m.xml - contains metadata
>   including session flags, socket reuse information, etc. The SAZ/ZIP
>   file's comment field contains information about the version of Fiddler
>   that generated the archive.
>
> SAZ files should always be forward/backward compatible, although some
>   features may be missing (e.g. socket reuse information) when loading
>   older files into the newest versions of Fiddler.
>
> SAZ Files MIME types are: application/x-fiddler-session-archive